# Is it legal to use string instead of integer to represent hash value of a string key?

Tags: data-structures, hash

For example: 
If key is "abc" my hash function will create "979899" (string) hash value, and I will store a hash value in a table using string type not int. 
All examples I found on the internet used integer to represent hash value.

Comment: It's perfectly "legal". The only question is: why would you want to do that? If strings are really more convenient than ints then go ahead and use strings. In many contexts, ints are more convenient. For instance, in a hashtable, the int produced by a hash function can be used directly as an array index. If your hash function produce a string, how are you going to use that string? If you use it as the key in a key-value structure (such as dict in python or std::map in c++), then under the hood, that string is going to be rehashed to produce an int.

Answer (score 2):

Legal maybe the wrong word. There's no law against strings!

It's perfectly fine to have hashes as strings.

For example, one of the most popular hash functions, SHA 256 returns a 64 character string that has both letters and numbers.

Comment: Well, SHA256 returns 256 bits. Those bits are usually represented as a hexadecimal string so they can be easily copied and pasted by humans. The "letters and numbers" you mention are hexadecimal digits (or "hexits" or "nibbles"): 0123456789abcdef.